# Display @ in TextView

Tags: android

How To display the Symbols: `@` and `"` in textView in android  i'm currently using the code

```
android:text="@" and
android:text="""
```

but it shows errors:

1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I also tried to put the value in to the String.But Same result.
it showed this error:"error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'atTheRate' with value '@')."

```
android:text="@string/atTheRate"
```

Comment: error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@'). and   1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: i got the right method to display the symbol " by using this code android:text="&quot;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it android:text="@" this should work fine but it seems that you missed the `=` sign  for `"` symbol use escape sequence character like this `\"` `android:text="\""`

update

```
android:text="@string/atTheRate"
```

the error occur since you don't have a string in your `strings.xml` resource file with the name of `atTheRate`

Comment: <string name="atTheRate">\@</string>  i used this in the String.xml and it shows no error but it displays \@

Comment: also used  android:text="\@" but it also displays \@

Comment: i got the right method to display the symbol " by using this code android:text="&quot;" but i also need to display the symbol @

Comment: go to java page and set Text there mean yout text view be tx then in java page tx.settext("@");

Answer (score 6):

you may try  `\u0040` instead of `\@`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. The error occurs because the API doesn't match. When I use the API level 17, the DatePicker doesn't work. So, I use the lower level API, like level 10, then the error does not exist.